# Data/file number limit in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am trying to load 4,729,699 files from s3 bucket using COPY Command  and am using trial version.
Its returning an error "Total size (>=1,073,742,040 bytes) for the list of file descriptors returned from the stage exceeded limit (1,073,741,824 bytes); Number of file descriptors returned is >=4,329,605. Please use a prefix in the stage location or pattern option to reduce the number of files."

May I know what is the maximum size limit in snowflake trial version  and if purchase its it will increase or not.

Comment: It looks like you have reached a limit on "when large number of files are being scanned from S3 location for metadata operation while creating the table".  Check this link https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-External-table-failing-with-error-code-001057-0A000

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size limit is already mentioned in the error message: 1,073,742,040 bytes.

As you see, it is measured by "bytes", so it's not about the maximum number of the files. The number of objects that can be added to the list depends on the lengths of the file names. In your case, 4,329,605 files were enough to reach the limit. That means each file consumed an average of 248 bytes.

As mentioned in the error message, you may use a prefix or pattern to reduce the number of files as a workaround.

This is not a limit specific to Trial accounts. If you need to increase the limit, you may contact Snowflake Support and describe the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to load `4,729,699` at once is rather a bad idea. One it did work. Two, even if it sometimes worked, the recovery from failure would be terrible.

Gokhan, is correct this is not a trial limit.

There are two classic reasons you have 4M objects in S3:

- you have N years worth of data. For this scenario instead of trying to load `/data/` load `/data/2019/`, then `/data/2020/` this way this list of objects returns from S3 will fit inside the limits.
- you have dump a large DB. In this scenario assuming some chunk base prefix/suffix try load of `a*.files`, then `b*.files`

while loading files is rather linear, when you have a bad file to handle, and you just spent 7 hours (made up number) loading your 1TB of data, and you find a problem and need to do the whole thing again, as you learn how to structure your query correctly, smaller batches make this all easier.

The other reason to batch file load is the response from the cloud file store is faster. If you are doing an on-going load, each 10 minutes, you don't need the list of files for the last 4 days, or 2 weeks, of 6 months, or 7 years, when there is only 3 new files per hour.